# How to prove that elementary row operations preserves the solution set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to understand how to proceed, if want to prove that elementary row operations ($R_i \rightarrow R_i + \lambda R_j$, with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, preserves the solution set (does not add or loose solutions).

Comment: This needs far more background and explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: An elementary row operation corresponds to an invertible linear transformation, $R$, that's an isomorphism of the domain $V$.  It follows that they preserve linear relations between the columns.

If $c_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$, then $Ax=b\iff x_1c_1+\dots +c_nx_n=b\iff x_1Rc_1+\dots+x_nRc_n=Rb$, where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.